Get data from called external function in Laravel
I created an external function in Laravel like this :
App\Controller\MyExternal\Function.php

And I write my payment gateway in this file and I send my data from my original controller to it like this:
$z_request = new MyExternal\ZRequest();
$z_request ->start_request(
    $amount,
    $invoice_name,
    $user_mobile
);

Everything work fine but in the end I must do redirect in my external function like this:
$startGateWayUrl = "https://gateway.com/start/".$response->trackId;
return redirect()->to($startGateWayUrl);

and I figured out that I can't make return or any redirect in called function.  So how I can pass back $startGateWayUrl to my main controller and doing redirect in it ?

return $startGateWayUrl;?

Your controller is doing something like $z_request->startGateWayURLmethod();, it should instead do return $z_request->startGateWayURLmethod();

This question is similar to: Redirect is not working when inside a method in laravel. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Don'tPanic not works $startGateWayUrl is an variable in another function

@ArunAS $startGateWayUrl is not defined in main controller

@SeyyedMohammadHosseini return $startGateWayUrl from your other function, or wherever it is. Then in your controller do something like return redirect()->away(yourOtherFunctionThatReturnsTheUrl());. If this is not possible, please update your question to include more details
